# average raster file value in shapefile area returns multiple outputs - interpreting results

Tags: r, shapefile, raster

So I have my raster file

```
r <- raster('ras')
```

and a shapefile

```
abys <- readShapeSpatial('abys')
```

I calculated the mean values defined by the shapefile by the following method:

```
r.vals<- extract(r,abys)
r.mean <- lapply(r.vals,FUN=mean)
```

However, when using a couple of shapefiles when I return the output I get multiple results, e.g.:

```
[[1]]
[1] 9321

[[2]]
[1] 6616

[[3]]
[1] 8348
```

It should just return one which is what I usually get. Is this because of some characterestic of my shapefile or a problem with my methodology?

Thanks for your input

Comment: I know nothing about this method but do you perchance have three polygons in your shapefile?  Ie what's length(abys)?

Comment: yes! so length(abys) shows there are 3 files (annoyingly simple) so my solution would be to calculate the mean from the 3 polygons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there are three polygons in `abys`.

The best solution is not to average the results but to union the polygon first:

```
library(rgeos)
abys.single <- gUnaryUnion(abys)
r.vals<- extract(r,abys.single)
r.mean <- lapply(r.vals,FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Can this be expanded to remove NA data? This has a value of -3000 so skews the mean

Comment: I actually sorted this be converting any values of -3000 to NA and then removing them

Comment: You can subset SpatialPolygonsDataFrames using `[,]` or `taRifx.geo::subset`.